# How to logically represent a smaller number being divided by a large number on a number line?

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility, fractions

Recently I asked this question on this platform:

When we divide a number by another number ($x \div y$), we can interpret it in two ways:

1. $x$ is divided in equal groups, where each group consists of $y$
2. $x$ is divided in $y$ equal groups

Suppose we divide $500 \div 5$. We can interpret this in two ways:

1. $500$ is divided in equal groups of $5$
2. $500$ is divided in $5$ equal groups

Now, if we divide $5 \div 500$, how can we interpret it in the same way?

I understood the $2nd$ interpretation for $5 \div 500$ from the answers. But I am not able to understand the $1st$ interpretation. I want to visualize the first interpretation on a number line.

In mathematics, if something is true, then it must be true for every scenario. Likewise, if we can interpret $500 \div 5$ in both ways on a number line, then we should be able to interpret $5 \div 500$ in both the ways on a number line too, right? How can $5$ be divided into equal groups, where each group contains $500$? If both the interpretations are applicable to $500 \div 5$ then it must be applicable to $5 \div 500$ too.

I would be grateful if someone can explain me this by visualizing it on a number line. Thank you for your time and efforts

Comment: One way of thinking of it on a number like is that $5/500$ is the number obtained by taking the number $5$ and shrinking the length between it and $0$ by a factor of 500. Just like multiplying by $500$ would increase the length of this segment by a factor of 500.

Comment: @whpowell96 Can you please elaborate it step wise, in detailed manner?

Comment: @Steve begin with a bunch of marbles. Now literally divide them up into groups of some fixed size. Eventually you'll get a certain number of piles all the same size and a partial pile remaining. The partial pile is the remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I interpret from your question, you seem to be stuck at how to divide 5 into equal groups of 500.

Firstly, this is a bad way to look at it. In math, proofs are always true for every scenario. What you have here are interpretations, or intuitions. These basically relate the concept of division into a simpler, more understandable form. But they won't always remain valid.

In your case, you want to find the number of groups of 500 that make up 5. You'll know that the answer is 0.01, but 0.01 groups makes no sense. The mistake lies in your assumption that your intuition will always stay true. Another example could be complex division. Say (3 + 4i)/(5 + 6i). This has no meaning in your two interpretations. The same goes for something like root(2)/root(5). There is simply no good intuition to generalize the concept of division.

While I do believe that intuition can help you get a feel of things in math, it is usually better to stick to the core concepts. You won't always be able to visualize everything.

Comment: I get what you are saying. I have a few questions though. What is the core concept here? And how to approach this for a better understanding? Is there any way to visualize this in an abstract manner, if not practically on the number line?

Comment: The core concept comes from multiplication. a/b gives a number n such that n*b = a. There isn't really much more to division beside this fact. It's one of the fundamental arithmetic operators in math. I'm afraid that I do not know of any other way to try and visualize it, if there is any. Though I do feel that you shouldn't overthink division that much. There isn't really that much to division. Also don't search too much on google. Various sites will provide you with various perspectives and interpretations which will just confuse you further.

Comment: Thank you for explain me this. I am very grateful. I was stuck at this for over 6 days. You explained it very well. If you are comfortable, can we connect on any platform? As here we cannot follow anyone. If you feel alright, I can send you my dummy mail id so no one has to share any details here. I am asking because you explain very well and I am self learning mathematics from the start and it would be great to have a mentor who can explain things in a simple manner, rather than confusing with different complex explanations, like most of the websites do. Thank you for your time

Comment: Hey man, no problem. We all have been stuck at some phase or another. Glad I was able to help. I would love to help out for any future ventures of yours as well, but unfortunately I won't be able to consistently answer your questions, as I'm in quite a busy phase of my life personally. I think the people here at stack exchange are quite knowledgeable and you should continue to post your doubts here. Best of luck on your journey!

Comment: That's alright. Thanks for the help!